# How to draw the shape shown in the below image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, tikz-styles, shapes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[fill=gray!20]([xshift=13mm, yshift=-23mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-13mm, yshift=-57mm]current page.north east);
\node[fill=blue, draw=none, signal, signal to=east, xshift=-25mm, yshift=9mm, minimum height=3.1cm, minimum width=3.6cm, scale=1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: current]

Intended (?) result:

[image]

Comment: Please see my edit ... looks like you either answered your question yourself or look for something else?

Answer (score 3):

You already have draw the arrow shape, you only need to place the text and the banner above and behind your shape.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[Violet!15] (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(-\pagewidth,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[Violet] (current page.north west) -- ++(0.07\pagewidth,0) -- ++(0.04\pagewidth,-1.5) -- ++(-0.04\pagewidth,-1.5) -- ++(-0.07\pagewidth,0) -- cycle;
        \node[color=Violet, font=\bfseries\LARGE\sffamily,anchor=center,xshift=0.5\pagewidth, yshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.north west) {Professional Reference Letter};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I'm getting error for \pagewidth

Answer (score 2):

From the work of Mane32, replacing `\pagewidth` by `\paperwidth`, by removing unused packages, and using the `calc` library.
I also added `\heigthheadband` for the height of the headband.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\heigthheadband}
\setlength{\heigthheadband}{3cm}
\tikzset{
    title/.style={
        color=violet,
        font=\bfseries\LARGE\sffamily,
        % anchor=center,
        xshift=0.5\paperwidth, 
        yshift=-0.5\heigthheadband,
        }
}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[Violet!15] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\heigthheadband)$);
        \fill[Violet] (current page.north west) -- ++(0.07\paperwidth,0) -- ++(0.04\paperwidth,-0.5\heigthheadband) -- ++(-0.04\paperwidth,-0.5\heigthheadband) -- ++(-0.07\paperwidth,0) -- cycle;
        \node[title] at (current page.north west) {Professional Reference Letter};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it has helped me a lot!

Comment: Could please tell me what does 0.08\paperwidth means in latex?

Comment: @Vishakha you can find the lengths used in the lshort documentation (in your native language) in english p.115 https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf
`0.08\paperwidth` is 0.08 x this length

Comment: Thanks I will definitely go through this!